# Make a new sniffer

Tags: linux, shell-script, scripting, linux-kernel, kernel-modules

How can use the Linux-kernel to supervise what is going on, about the new connections, new ports, connected hosts? Like I will do a new sniffer.
Which files should I monitor to know what is going around.

For example, if a server have no ssh connections, then a new host is connected using port 22 , i want to have alert for this new connection. If the host is disconnected, another alert will be run.

Comment: have a look at the netlink protocol, it provides you information about network details. What do you mean with ports? ports as in TCP/UDP?

Comment: Yes, i mean TCP/UDP ports. I want just to be update to what is happening for these ports ( new connections ...)

Answer (score 2):

Bit vague but... Netstat shows the status of currently open connections for the local machine, there's stuff in /proc/net that you could do some clever 'real time' stuff on, or there's programs like tcpdump which will give you raw packet logs (you can create a filter if you're interested in more specific things), along with tools like wireshark for the packet log analysis.  What /exactly/ is your goal, it might help advise better.

Comment: My goal is to know which ports are used, the status of every port (down , up)

Comment: The expression "ports going up and down" is usually used in the context of actual "links" going up and down, e.g. pulling out the cable makes the link go down, putting it in makes the link go up.  These events are (usually, probably driver dependant) logged in the syslog " NIC Copper Link is Up, 1000 Mbps full duplex" and "em1: link becomes ready".  That has very little to do with any of the commands I listed, and normally (from the computer software POV) ports refer to TCP or UDP port numbers, but those dont go "up" and "down".

Comment: I just want to know , is there a host connected using a port , which are used and which not .

Comment: netstat then.  my favorite options are "netstat -ap" personally (or -anp if you dont want to wait forever on DNS)

Comment: But, "netstat -ap" will print the TCP/UDP ports status for the moment of running the command. I will not have a report when a new host is connected or disconnected. I want to be update to what is happening

Comment: iptables LOG target to log when tcp connection establishment occurs?  more out of luck with UDP really, thats gonna be a fun logfile!

Answer (score 0):

If it just to have an instant view on what IP are connected and which connection is generating network trafic,  you could try `iptraf`.

If you want more features like  accounting, graphs and remote monitoring you could try  `ntop`.  `Ntop` runs as a deamon, monitoring and administration are made with a browser at localhost:3000.